# BroadCast Receiver Triggering

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to simply call one function that is defined in BroadClass Activity from my AlarmManager Activity. For this I have made one broadcast Receiver and i am triggering it from Alarmmanager Activity , but I am getting no response

AlarmManager Activity ( TRIGGERING Broadcast from here)

```
 package com.mainActivity;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class AlarmManagerActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmManagerActivity.this,BroadClass.class);
            intent.setAction("BROADCAST_ACTION");
            sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
    }
```

BroadClass Activity where I have defined the Broadcast Reciever

```
   package com.mainActivity;


    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Toast;



    public class BroadClass extends Activity {

        public BroadcastReceiver broadCast;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(BroadClass.this, "SDK Manager Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


myFunction();   //which i want to call

                }
            },new IntentFilter("BROADCAST_ACTION"));


        }


        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction("BROADCAST_ACTION");
            registerReceiver(broadCast, filter);

            super.onResume();


        }

public void myFunction(){

//mycode here

    }
```

Kindly Help me..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried removing the BroadcastReceiver setup in onResume? You're registering a new broadcastreceiver with an empty IntentFilter.

Remember, onResume is always run after onCreate, and in your case resetting the filter that was initially set.

Comment: Yes I have tried removing it from onResume.Still getting not response. I think my BroadCast reciever is not registere at the time of sending a broadcast. Please help me to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmManagerActivity.this,BroadClass.class);`

to

`Intent intent = new Intent();`

Also make sure that the receiver is registered at the time the broadcast is being sent.
Oh and don't forget to unregister the receiver when leaving the activity. Otherwise you will get nasty exceptions.